# Fill in bits in an array to make array a certain length

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I'm turning a string into an array of arrays of bits and it all works, but I need to make all of the arrays the same length.
Example:
If I have the string "hello world" I get these bit values for each character

```
1110100
1011110
1111101
1101110
111010
1110100
1100101
1101100
1101101
```

In my array of arrays it looks like this

```
[ [ '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0' ],
  [ '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0' ],
  [ '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1' ],
  [ '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0' ],
  [ '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0' ],
  [ '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0' ],
  [ '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1' ],
  [ '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0' ],
  [ '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1' ] ]
```

I need to make it so that they are all the same length by adding 0's to the beginning of them until they are all the same length (the length of the longest one)
With this working, I want to turn something like that into something like this so that all of the rows are the same length whilst not changing the actual character it represents.

```
[ [ '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0' ],
  [ '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0' ],
  [ '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1' ],
  [ '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0' ],
  [ '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0' ],
  [ '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0' ],
  [ '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1' ],
  [ '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0' ],
  [ '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1' ] ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first use `Array#reduce` to find the maximum length and then use `Array#map` to pad all of the arrays with leading zeroes if necessary.

```js
let arr = [ [ '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0' ],
  [ '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0' ],
  [ '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1' ],
  [ '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0' ],
  [ '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0' ],
  [ '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0' ],
  [ '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1' ],
  [ '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0' ],
  [ '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1' ] ];
let maxLen = arr.reduce((acc,curr)=>Math.max(acc,curr.length), 0);
let res = arr.map(x => Array(maxLen - x.length).fill('0').concat(x));
res.forEach(x => console.log(...x));
```

Comment: Was not aware of array.fill. Neat.

Answer (score 0):

You could join, padStart, and split each item:

```js
const bits = ['1','1'].join('').padStart(8, '0').split('');

// [ '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1']
```